# Twilio: how to hangup Programmable Voice Call without leaving voicemail if not answered

Tags: twilio, voice

I tried Programmable Voice Call using TwilML   Your new ID number is 12345  to instruct what to say when the phone is answered. It works but if the call is not answered it leaves voicemail, which I do not want to. If the call is not answered how can I just hangup without leaving voicemail.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this blog, to see how to go about detecting VM using key press detection. Another option is Answering Machine Detection.

You can use keypress detection (Human Detection) with both a TwiML Dial and API call where AMD can only be used when making an API call to the ‘Call resource.

[Outsmart Voice Mail with Human Detection Using Keypress Prompts](https://www.twilio.com/blog/voice-mail-human-detection-studio-functions)

[How to Use Twilio Async Answering Machine Detection](https://www.twilio.com/blog/async-answering-machine-detection-tutorial)